# Mongoose: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, unhandled-promise-rejection

I know there are other posts with similar issues, but none of the suggestions I've tried have worked.

The following works if the _id is valid, but throws an unhandled promise rejection error if it isn't:

```
const Movie = mongoose.model(`Movie`, movieSchema);


router.get(`/api/movies/:id`, async (req, res) => {
    let movie = await Movie.findById(req.params.id);

    if(!movie) {
        res.status(404).send(`Movie with given ID not found.`);
        return;
    };
});
```

Per the docs, it looks like findById() is supposed to return null if the id can't be found, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Do I need to put a catch block somewhere and put the 404 in there? I've tried putting it everywhere I can think to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use .then() and .catch() will sort your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById)...

> #### Model.findById()
>
> **Returns:**
>
> - «Query»

Looking into the [Query API](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html), when used like a `Promise`, it will invoke the [Query.prototype.then()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-then) implementation

> Executes the query returning a `Promise` which will be resolved with either the doc(s) or **rejected with the error**.

To use this, you would need something like

```js
try {
  const movie = await Movie.findById(req.params.id)
  // do stuff with movie
} catch (err) {
  res.sendStatus(404)
}
```

Comment: I tried this too, same result. I should've mentioned this though, good shout.

Comment: Tried what? There are two code snippets in my answer

Comment: I tried using let movie = await Movie.findById(req.params.id).exec();

Comment: @William the docs for the return value of `exec()` aren't super clear (it just says `«Promise»`, not very helpful) but it seems perhaps that code comment mentioning `null` isn't accurate. I would go with the `try..catch` implementation